# JRegistry exists() returns empty array

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I was trying to save a form data to DB. In the controller save() function there is a statement

```
$data = $model->validate($form, $data);
```

But it always returns empty. I tracked down the problem to the filter() function in /libraries/joomla/form/form.php (comes with joomla package). Here is some code (shortened):

```
    $input = new JRegistry($data);
    $output = new JRegistry;

    foreach ($fields as $field)
    {   
            // Initialise variables.
            $name = (string) $field['name'];  
    if ($input->exists($name)){
       $output->set($name, $this->filterField($field, $input->get($name, (string)  field['default'])));
    }      
}
```

$input looks like :

```
JRegistry Object ( [data:protected] => stdClass Object ( [jform] => stdClass Object ( [title] => Utility Model/Patent application [ap_name] => d ...) [option] => com_eipoapplications [task] => save ) )
```

And each $name in the loop always contain the form element name (like 'title', 'ap_name' ... ).
But the if conditional statement always returns false. Does any one help me know why JRegistry exists() function is not finding the elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are having an inconsistency between form and data.

Let's say the form contains a field with name `title`.
$data array should have a value under key of same name:

```
$data = array(
  'title' => 'Utility Model/Patent application',
  'ap_name' => 'd'
);
```

Or using print_r

```
Array
(
    [title] => Utility Model/Patent application
    [ap_name] => d
)
```

If there's no data for such field, validation is omitted. If all data keys are wrong, function returns empty array.

The question is, how it happened :/

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Let me add more info.

Comment: If you are not using native [JControllerLegacy->save](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/legacy/controller/form.php#L550), make sure `$data` is properly populated from post: `$data  = $this->input->post->get('jform', array(), 'array');` and form control name  in model is `jform`

Comment: $data looks like : `Array ( [jform] => Array ( [title] => Utility Model/Patent application [ap_name] => d`. I think the problem is JRegistry adds another layer of object and put the jform under [data:protected] index. This layer makes the form elements (eg. title) hidden from JRegistry exists() function. Is there another way around?

Comment: This is how JRegistry works, this is fine, `$data` are wrong :). Somehow you are not getting the `jform` array, but probably whole POST data. Please check that you are retrieving `$data` as in my comment above. A non-standard solution would be to pass data for validation like this: `$data = $model->validate($form, $data['jform']);`. How are you retrieving initial `$data` variable?

Comment: Thank you pio. That was the problem. I used `$data = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getArray($_POST);` which puts the whole $_POST content under jform (jform->array(POST ITEMS HERE)). I want to know more about JControllerLegacy. Is there any place to go? Thank you again!

Comment: If you are not doing anything special, just name the controller method **save** and parent class will handle all for you (data retrieval, validation, permission checks, calling model->save, handling errors). Best knowledge source is series [**J2.5:Developing a MVC Component**/Adding backend actions](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_backend_actions). You may also check [Retrieving request data using JInput](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput)